# SFTP or NFS to share files with Linux server? (Windows Server 2012 R2)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, airflow

I am looking for a solution which will allow a Linux server to access regular Windows shared folders on a scheduled basis.

My current solution for this was using a Docker SFTP image and mapping a volume to a host folder (uploads). The end user would drop a file on a Windows machine, but this was actually an SFTP folder. I would then grab the file using a SSH hook.

Requirements are:

1. The Windows folder should look and feel like any other Windows shared folder and use Active Directory (permissions will be based on the NT ID, per folder, and will be managed by someone who is only familiar with Windows, end user simply navigates to \server\folder to drop their files using Explorer).
2. I do not want the end user to need WinSCP installed, or to use a separate username/password
3. The Linux server would access the files from these folders to process them (Airflow ETL tool)

The computer I am using now is Windows Server 2012 R2 so I can't install Docker for Windows directly, and I do not want to use the Virtual Box alternative. Apparently, I can set up an SFTP on Windows (unsure what the best software to use is). I also created a test shared folder using NFS instead of SMB because it seems like Linux can share files with that format, but I didn't explore it too much.

What's the best approach?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

you can create ftp(ssh) server on Linux.
On Windows you can mount this share by creating network drive.

You can find how to do it by this article

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/map-an-ftp-drive-windows